Potential unintended optout mistaken by One-Click when auto link checker imposed
Hi salesforce community,
I am examining the potential problem of unintended unsubscription being mistakenly triggered, possibly due to unknown email link checkers operating on the recipients' side.
The issue becomes apparent when there are some opt-out records indicate that all email links, including the one-click unsubscribe link, have been clicked at the exact same timespan, leading to unsubscription later on.
Please share if you have detected the similar issue and if there are any potential solutions.
Thanks
